# Trying to problem solve a broken link Laravel Installation (using MAMP)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm really not sure what to do to solve this. I've been able to run a Laravel Installation from a repo (using git) but when I run `php artisan serve` then the page loads but all the URL's are broken.

If you view source and I click, for example, a CSS file then that remains broken but if I change the path from `http://nestdb.local` to `http://localhost:8000/` then the path loads fine and I can view source the CSS so that shows that correct path must be `http://localhost:8000/`

It seems like a basic problem to fix but I am not sure what to do.

The recommendations based on a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944168/trying-to-problem-solve-broken-links-in-a-laravel-installation) suggested editing the `.env file` which I've tried but to no success.

Is it is `etc/hosts` issue? or a MAMP Virtual Hosts issue?

This is my hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 nestdb.local
127.0.0.1 nest.test
127.0.0.1 nestdb.test
# 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 test.test
```

I'm really at a loss here and am pretty desperate to fix this...

This is my MAMP Virtual Hosts doc:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/henry/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestdb2017/public"
    ServerName nestdb.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the `.env file`

```
APP_ENV=localwg
APP_KEY=base64:DRzwryVj12XXXXXXXXSpKzqI8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000/
APP_TIMEZONE = Asia/Hong_Kong

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nestlaravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

MY_HOST=nestdb.local
PRODUCTION_SERVER=1
HOST_ROOT=http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: If you using MAMP you don't need to serve the application.

Comment: But it I don't run that command then the application doesn't load, so I have to it seems...so I'll visit http://localhost:8000/ and it's a dead page, if I run the command then it loads ok just with broken links for CSS etc

Comment: Make sure you're using relative links for all of your CSS/JS instead of specifying the domain.

Comment: MAMP is like a server. Mamp has Apache, MySQL, and PHP. So you don't need to serve it. You have nestdb.local at `/etc/hosts` file. Load all CSS and JS file from that URL. You don't need `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: The problem is that nestdb.local URL does NOT load - only the http://localhost:8000 does

Comment: What are you using for your CSS links, in your code? Are you using `http://localhost:8000/css`, or `/css`?